# How to Restore wordpress website from “domain_date_time.tar” backup file from hosting’s ‘application_backup’ folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, hosting

How to Restore wordpress website from **domain_date_time.tar** backup file from hosting’s **application_backup** folder? Is there any method to bring back complete website back to live state this compressed wordpress backup file. Please help

My website was hacked, had to reset complete hosting

No Manual backup was created before for the websiteexcept an automatic backup from installatron wordpress interface, which raside on hosting’s root directory inside application_backup folder.

This compressed backup .tar file has  following files& folders inside

```
Wp-admin
Wp-content
Wp-includes
 .htaccess
APP-DATA.SQL
APP-META.INI
Index.php
License.txt
Wp-activate.php
Wp-blog-header.php
Wp-config.php
Wp-config-sample.php
Wp-cron.php
Wp-links-oml.php
Wp-load.php
Wp-login.php
Wp-mail.php
Wp-settings.php
Wp-signup.php
Wp-trackback.php
Xmlrpc.php
```

Hosting was godaddy shared, this backup date is 18 may 2016, post reset of hosting servers hosting region changed from USA to Asia. Please revert if anyone knows how to manually backup the way hosting provider does.

Answer (score 0):

Well along with these files you will need a database backup file. Once you get it. create new database using cPanel. 
inport database with your backed up .sql file. 
copy these files to public-html folder.
open wp-config file replace your old database username and password with new one. and its done.

Answer (score 0):

well , make sure you have proper permissions set too after restoring those files.